# BatchGetItem for a list of key variables for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I understand we need to pass-in attribute name and primary key names for BatchGetItem of DDB. Like:

```
TableKeysAndAttributes forumTableKeysAndAttributes = new TableKeysAndAttributes(forumTableName);
// Add a partition key
forumTableKeysAndAttributes.addHashOnlyPrimaryKeys("Animal", "cat", "dog");

BatchGetItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchGetItem(forumTableKeysAndAttributes,threadTableKeysAndAttributes);
```

So here we manually pass-in attribute name "animal", and two primary key (two types of animals dog and cat). (Correct me if I'm wrong)

But what if now I have a list of primary key, that is `[dog, cat, cow, rabbit, sheep, chicken...]` which comes in the form of `List<String>`, obviously I can't manually pass in them, then what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a list of hash keys:

```
List<String> keys
```

You can call the `addHashOnlyPrimaryKeys` method like this:

```
forumTableKeysAndAttributes.addHashOnlyPrimaryKeys("Animal", keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]));
```

The question you have asked here is basically to pass a list as arguments to a vararg method.